# Cannot associate events to calendars in Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar

[image: Solspace Calendar]
I have just installed Solspace Calendar 1.8.14 for EE 2.10.1.

I have added three calendars, and three events. When I try to associate an event to a calendar, nothing happens. When I click "Add Rule" nothing happens. Also, when I manually set the dates and times, nothing happens. In each scenario after I click submit, I am returned to the submission confirmation page... the "Edit This Entry, Return to Filtered Entries, Publish Another Entry or View Comments (0)" page. AND when I choose to edit, the updates are not there.

The editor page looks like something is broken, see attached screen grab. Any suggestions as to what I should check? or do? Is this a bug with EE? Calendar or a conflict with an existing module?

I have set permissions for admins and contributors to be able to post to the channel. I am a super admin so permissions shouldn't matter anyway.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it did not install correctly. Specifically some things from the themes seem to be missing. Make sure you uploaded the /themes/third_party/calendar folder.

Comment: That was it. Upon re-installing the add-on, the missing theme directory got added. Thank you for your help.